# Node.js write a CD/DVD api?

Tags: node.js, api, dvd, cddvd

Is there a way to write data on a CD/DVD with Node.js? I've tried to find information but I couldn't find alot beside Linux CD/DVD eject feature.

Platform I'm using: Windows.

Comment: Easiest way would be probably calling the command line interface of ImgBurn (or other similar software): http://www.avsforum.com/forum/26-home-theater-computers/1402080-using-imgburn-command-line-batch.html